# Looking for sutta about purification of fish, turtles, etc

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras

Is there are sutta in which the Buddha says if bathing in Ganges River could purify beings; then the fish, turtles, crocodiles, etc, would be purified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in Therigatha:

> [The Brahman:]
> Punnika, surely you know.
> You're asking one doing skillful kamma
> & warding off evil.
> Whoever, young or old, does evil kamma
> is, through water ablution,
> from evil kamma set free.
>
> [Punnika:]
> Who taught you this
> — the ignorant to the ignorant —
> 'One, through water ablution,
> is from evil kamma set free?'
> **In that case, they'd all go to heaven:
>
> all the frogs, turtles,
>
> serpents, crocodiles,
>
> & anything else that lives in the water.**
> Sheep-butchers, pork-butchers,
> fishermen, trappers,
> thieves, executioners,
> & any other evil doers,
> would, through water ablution,
> be from evil kamma set free.
> [Therigatha 12.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thig/thig.12.01.than.html)

Another related sutta:

> The Buddha said to Sangarava:
>
> “Is it really true, brahmin, that you practice purification by water,
> believing in purification by water; that you live committed to the
> practice of immersing yourself in water at dawn and dusk?”
>
> “Yes, Master Gotama.”
>
> “But brahmin, for what reason do you practice purification by water?”
>
> “It’s because, Master Gotama, whatever bad deeds I’ve done during the
> day I wash off by bathing at dusk; and whatever bad deeds I’ve done
> during the night, I wash off by bathing at dawn. That’s the reason why
> I practice purification by water.”
>
> > “The teaching is a lake with shores of ethics, brahmin,
> > unclouded, praised by the fine to the good.
> > There the knowledge-masters go to bathe,
> > and cross to the far shore without getting wet.”
>
> When he had spoken, Saṅgārava said to the Buddha:
>
> “Excellent, Master Gotama! Excellent! … From this day forth, may
> Master Gotama remember me as a lay follower who has gone for refuge
> for life.”
> [SN 7.21](https://suttacentral.net/sn7.21/en/sujato)

Comment: thank you sir..

Comment: Can you please change my username to "Order of the Lotus Irelia"? I can't change it for 30 days.